# Error of Ruby on Rails 5 Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

#### Version Info.

Ruby 2.5.1
Rails 5.2.0

Now I am building a new website with Ruby on Rails. On the directory( `/config/environments/development.rb`), I wrote the following codes.

```
config.aciton_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  authentication: :plain,
  user_name: Rails.application.secrets.SMTP_EMAIL,
  password: Rails.application.secrets.SMTP_PASSWORD
}
```

The error message is

> method_missing': undefined method｀ aciton_mailer

I would like to use 'Devise Gem' in order to user configuration. Users register own e-mail address and username, then system sends an e-mail to them with hyperlink. They click the link, they register full user information on their profile page.

Now there are some bugs, and  'action mailer ' does not work , but I cannot find the cause. By Google, they say it seems the difference of Ruby or Rails versions.

If you find any ideas from this posts, i would like you to teach me the idea. I guess the idea will inspire me to solve this problem.

Comment: where did you write this config.action_mailer code in development.rb file ?

Comment: Once you fix your typo you might want to look into something like [MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me) for working with email in development, much easier than actually sending email through Gmail.

Comment: Thank you for your advising. I confirm it at 3 times, but I did not find this spelling miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with your spelling, it's not `aciton`, it's `action`:

Not `aciton_mailer`:

```
config.aciton_mailer.smtp_settings = {
```

It should `action_mailer`:

```
config.acton_mailer.smtp_settings = {
```

Full code:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  authentication: :plain,
  user_name: Rails.application.secrets.SMTP_EMAIL,
  password: Rails.application.secrets.SMTP_PASSWORD
}
```

Comment: Thank you for polite message.
I understand to mistake spelling fully.